# \detailref or \autoref without pagenumber when on same page?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm looking for a way to use `\detailref` or `\autoref` with pagenumber output, but only where necessary. The pagenumber shall be suppressed when the reference target is on the same page. How do I do that?

Comment: The [`varioref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) provides this functionality.

Comment: Looks promising. Is `varioref` available in German?

Comment: I've never needed to use `varioref`, but I imagine you can tailor the output (and therefore make it language-specific).

Comment: `varioref` has a `german` option according to the manual.

Comment: @Werner An answer?

Answer (score 1):

I extended Werner's comment to an answer using `varioref`. For your purpose showing real page numbers instead of e.g. `auf der vorherigen Seite` you need the `\renewcommand`'s (see documentation) in the following code.

Here's the output for page one and two of the following example:

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[german]{varioref}

\renewcommand\reftextfaceafter {auf Seite~\thevpagerefnum}
\renewcommand\reftextfacebefore{auf Seite~\thevpagerefnum}
\renewcommand\reftextafter {auf Seite~\thevpagerefnum}
\renewcommand\reftextbefore {auf Seite~\thevpagerefnum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{Test}\label{fig:test}
    \end{figure}
    \vref{fig:test}\\\vpageref{fig:test}
    \clearpage
    \vref{fig:test}\\\vpageref{fig:test}
\end{document}
```